# Pseudo-truly random number generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, reinventing-the-wheel

I am creating what strives to be a truly random number generator. As of right now, the implementation uses a mix of mainly nonsense system data and some pseudo-random numbers to generate numbers that are different and use the last half of the number (which, statistically, I believe is sufficiently random). The advice I would like:

1. Obviously, a general "review", as always.
2. How can I optimize this code to be faster? Currently, generating ten 1000 digit numbers takes two seconds, ten 10000 digit numbers takes 35-37 seconds, and ten 100000 digit numbers is exponentially slower.
3. How practical is this? Currently the generator uses some methods which may be considered "hacky"; ergo, using the last half of a number, or including pseudo-random numbers in the algorithm. Is this OK? I believe it should be, as long as the numbers generated are indeed random, but I would like other's opinions on this.

Another thing to note is that when testing some sample batches with [this online tester](https://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/Business-stat/otherapplets/Randomness.htm), I got p-values around 0.24, which I believe is the optimal range. If you answer, don't feel pressured to answer all three questions.

```
import os, re, time, random
from functools import reduce

def rand_num(digits=3):
  nums = []
  strs = []
  rand = []
  add = True
  all_info = re.sub('(.*?: *)','',os.popen("cat /proc/meminfo").read()).replace('kB','').splitlines()+list(filter(None,re.findall(r'(\w*)',os.popen('ps').read())))
  all_info = list(x.strip() for x in all_info)
  nums.append(random.sample(range(digits*70), digits*35))
  nums = nums[0]
  for x in all_info:
    if x.isdigit():
      nums.append(int(x))
    else:
      strs.append(x)
  jugglenum = 0
  for x in nums:
    if add == True:
      jugglenum += x
      add = False
    else:
      jugglenum -= x
      add = True
  jugglenum = abs(jugglenum)
  for i in range(digits):
    rand.append(int(time.time()*(os.getpid()%jugglenum)))
  for i, x in enumerate(rand):
    rand[i] = ''.join(random.sample(str(x), len(str(x))))
  rand = [int(x)//10 for x in rand]
  largenum = str(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, rand))[:digits]
  return ''.join(random.sample(random.sample(largenum,len(largenum)),len(largenum)))
```

An executable program on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@xMikee/TRNG).

Yes, I know, this is similar to `random.SystemRandom` or `os.urandom`. This program I am developing now is really my first look into this concept and I don't plan for this to be my final program by any means. This is just something that I thought I would play around with for the time being.

So before you go and tell me that this is pointless and could have no application, I know. This is just my own personal experiment so I can get better at this sort of program.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some great suggestions from other users here (thanks a lot everyone!) I was able to improve the program and reduce its size by about 10%. Here is the updated program:

```
import os, re, time, random, subprocess as sp
from functools import reduce

def rand_num(digits=3):
  rand=[];strs=[]
  all_info = re.sub('(.*?: *)','',open('/proc/meminfo').read()).replace('kB','').splitlines()+list(filter(None,re.findall(r'(\w*)',sp.Popen('ps', stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().decode())))
  all_info = list(x.strip() for x in all_info)
  nums = random.sample(range(digits*70), digits*35)
  nums.extend([int(x) for x in all_info if x.isdigit()])
  strs.extend([x for x in all_info if not x.isdigit()])
  jugglenum = abs(sum(nums[::2])-sum(nums[1::2]))
  for i in range(digits):
    rand.append(int(time.time()*(os.getpid()%jugglenum)))
  rand = [''.join(random.sample(str(x), len(str(x)))) for x in rand[:]]
  rand = [int(x)//10 for x in rand]
  largenum = str(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, rand))[:digits]
  return ''.join(random.sample(random.sample(largenum,len(largenum)),len(largenum)))
```

I managed to get most of the large functions down to one-liners that run much faster and produce impressive results. I also managed to reduce the size of the function by about 10%, from over 1000 bytes to about 900 bytes.

I ran both scripts with `timeit`, testing how long it took to do ten runs producing numbers of a set length. Here's the results to produce ten 1, 10, 100, 1000, and 10000 digit numbers with both scripts:

```
Old script:

Ones:          0.4990974200045457
Tens:          0.6853595590000623
Hundreds:      1.0144964690043707
Thousands:     5.584901581998565
Ten-thousands: 40.79681804100255

----

New script:

Ones:          0.11410925599921029
Tens:          0.17456803799723275
Hundreds:      0.3204780189989833
Thousands:     2.4103602649993263
Ten-thousands: 30.67583657600335
```

Comment: Still: don't do ten things on one line. You're shooting yourself and every developer that touches the code after you in both feet.

Comment: @Reinderien Which line are you talking about? I find it useful to do that both for speed, and because it makes sense to execute an operation that is all mentally grouped together just in one go.

Comment: I'm talking about this line: `all_info = re.sub('(.*?: *)','',open('/proc/meminfo').read()).replace('kB','').splitlines()+list(filter(None,re.findall(r'(\w*)',sp.Popen('ps', stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().decode())))` - what you're doing is called premature optimization. Grouping things onto one line might strip off a few nanoseconds from parse time, but since your script is only parsed once, doing this has absolutely no effect on execution time.

Comment: But don't take my word for it - measure both and post the results :)

Comment: @Reinderien Speaking of which, one of the times just finished: 1072.1309 seconds for generating ten hundred-thousand digit numbers with the old script. I'll see if it finishes for the new script soon enough; I might have to stop it for the night.

Comment: @Reinderien I have updated with the results.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of minor simplifications:

---

```
nums =[]
...
nums.append(random.sample(...))
nums = nums[0]
```

could be replaced with:

```
nums = random.sample(...)
```

---

The `add`/`jugglenum` loop calculation could be done with:

```
jugglenum = abs(sum(nums[::2]) - sum(nums[1::2]))
```

---

This code:

```
for i, x in enumerate(rand):
    rand[i] = ''.join(random.sample(str(x), len(str(x))))
```

could be replaced with:

```
rand = [ ''.join(random.sample(s, len(s)) for s in (str(x) for x in rand)]
```

which eliminates the enumeration and avoids turning `x` into a `str(x)` twice.

---

I don’t see `strs` being used anywhere, so the code that calculates it can be removed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, your changes acctually made the program significantly slower (which was much unexpected to me considering how messy my code is).

Comment: Oops.  Did you profile it to see which of the 3 changes made it slower?  My money is on the `iter`+`zip`+`sum` change, which is good because I think I over complicated that cleanup.  `jugglenum = abs(sum(nums[::2])-sum(nums[1::2]))` is 3 lines shorter, clearer, and probably faster.

Comment: OK, that definitely fixed the speed. Interestingly enough, however, your list comp is actually significantly slower than the enumeration method. I'm really scratching my head with this one - shouldn't list comps be much faster than enumerates?

Comment: Actually: disregard that. I was having problems with other parts of the code. You can actually [run it if you want](https://repl.it/@xMikee/TRNG), it's much faster now.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments:

```
all_info = re.sub('(.*?: *)','',os.popen("cat /proc/meminfo").read()).replace('kB','').splitlines()+list(filter(None,re.findall(r'(\w*)',os.popen('ps').read())))
```

"can" is not "should". You "should" not do this. This should be probably upwards of four lines. Also, `popen` is deprecated in favour of `subprocess`. Even so, don't use `cat`. Simply open the file.

More generally, you should do some reading on entropy.